# Java Web Start - Multiple shortcuts

Tags: java, windows-xp, shortcut, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm having a problem with creating shortcuts at versions of WindowsXP that aren't in English.

I want to add a shortcut to the 'Startup' menu, that way, the application will run every time the user log on.

So i did:

```
<shortcut online="true">
    <desktop/>
    <menu submenu="Startup"/>
</shortcut>
```

But, at WindowsXP in Portuguese, for example, the correct submenu need to be 'Inicializar' instead of 'Startup'.

So, considering that application's users may have English or Portuguese versions of Windows, I need something like that:

```
<shortcut online="true">
    <desktop/>
    <menu submenu="Startup"/>
</shortcut>
<shortcut online="true">
        <desktop/>
        <menu submenu="Inicializar"/>
</shortcut>
```

But that doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to provide different jnlps for different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JNLP format supports partitioning downloads by locales in the `resources` elements, but not the `shortcuts` element (from memory - use [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) to check for sure).

Instead, you will probably need to look to the [`IntegrationService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html) introduced in 6.0.18.  Particularly the [`requestShortcut(desktop,menu,submenu)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html#requestShortcut%28boolean,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String%29)<sup>1</sup> method.  The method returns a `boolean` to indicate success/failure.

1. The string for `submenu` might be inferred from:

   - `user.language`
   - `Locale.getDefault()`
   - The simple solutions - ask the user:

     1. Editable combo-box of known variants in an option pane.
     2. A file chooser, pointing to somewhere near where the start menu should be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I provided two jnlps for my clients. It was the faster way to resolve the problem considering the project's urgency

Answer (score 3):

I did this in my app:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegrationService is = null;
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");

        try {
            is = (IntegrationService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.IntegrationService");
        } catch (UnavailableServiceException use) {
            use.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!is.hasMenuShortcut()) {
            if (osName.equals("Windows 7")) {
                is.requestShortcut(false, true, "Startup");
            } else {
                is.requestShortcut(false, true, "Inicializar");
            }
        }
        SystemTrayTest main = new SystemTrayTest();
    }
```

So in Windows XP the shortcut is created in "Inicializar" and Windows 7 in "Startup".

Comment: `if (!is.hasMenuShortcut()) {`  If is is `null`, that will cause an NPE.  That code should be moved inside the `try`.  Alternately, check for `null` before proceeding `if (is!=null && !is.hasMenuShortcut()) {`